# Upload Form in playframework error 413 request entity to large

Tags: playframework

This here his the Controller Action also, can I make this async(just curious)?

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request => 
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
        import java.io.File
        val filename = picture.filename 
        val contentType = picture.contentType
        picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture"))
        Ok("File uploaded")
      }.getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
          "error" -> "Missing file"
        )
      }
  }
```

Route

```
GET     /admin/carro/upload         controllers.AdminCarro.upload
```

Template

```
@import helper._


@main(new Main("Car Dealers", "Compra e venda de carros", "logo.png", "carro, compra, venda")) {
    <div class="container">
    @form(routes.AdminCarro.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

        <input type="file" name="picture">

        <p>
            <input type="submit">
        </p>

    }
    </div>
}
```

This 413 Request entity to large happens without sending any file or having anything presented.

Comment: When it happens? Are you sending a request to `/admin/carro/upload` without a file?

Comment: Yes. It's just a simple request to present the page form and nothing shows just the 413 error is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by doing it like this. Why don't you present the view with a **`GET`** and the upload with a **`POST`**:

```
def uploadView = Action.async { request => 
   Future.successful(Ok(views.html.uploadForm))
}

def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData).async { request => 
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
        import java.io.File
        val filename = picture.filename 
        val contentType = picture.contentType
        picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture"))
        Future.successful(Ok("File uploaded"))
      }.getOrElse {
        Future.successful(Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
          "error" -> "Missing file"
        ))
      }
  }
```

And the routes file:

```
  GET     /admin/carro/upload         controllers.AdminCarro.uploadView
  POST    /admin/carro/upload         controllers.AdminCarro.upload
```

Also if you are uploading large files you could specify the max sixe for all parsers:

```
parsers.text.maxLength=5242880
```

or for Action

```
Action(parse.text(maxLength = 1024 * 10))
```

Comment: I'm used to PHP where I can in the same REQUEST separate a POST from a GET Request simply, and without  problems. :\ Curious if this is the same for Java and JavaServlets?

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature ;) although in PHP request methods can be mixed it is not advised as it compromise the security. De facto developer should expect exact method on each request and that's how the Play works (for an instance application returns 404 if there's no defined POST route, instead `forwarding` it to GET) Matter of taste, I prefer safer approach. In previous version of Play (branch 1.x) exists a wildcard method __*__ (asterisk) which stands for __any__ method, anyway in the name of security it was avoided in Play 2.x